# SSRS Multi-Select and For-Each Stored-Procs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using an SSRS multi-select which gives me an unknown number of values > 0.  That is something like the following (1),(4),...(x).

I want to union the results of a stored procedure for each ID that SQL receives.

If this came as a table my job would be easier.

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| ... |
| x |

I found the following code got me a good way there:

```sql
DECLARE @MyTempTable TABLE (txtType NVARCHAR(20), intID integer, txtAccountCode NVARCHAR(50), txtSchoolID NVARCHAR(50), txtSageCode NVARCHAR(50), ChargeCode NVARCHAR(50),
       txtDescription NVARCHAR(200), mAmount DECIMAL(18,2), percentageAmount DECIMAL(18,2), txtChargeType NVARCHAR(50), txtNominalAccount NVARCHAR(50), bBilledInAdvance BIT)

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @CycleId int
DECLARE @numrows int
DECLARE @Cycle Table (
    idx smallint IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CycleId int
)

INSERT @Cycle (CycleId)
SELECT [TblFeeBillingCycleID] FROM [TblFeeBillingCycle] WHERE  [TblFeeBillingCycleID] IN(@intCycleId)

SET @i = 1
SET @numrows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Cycle)
IF @numrows > 0
    WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @Cycle))
    BEGIN

        SET @CycleId = (SELECT CycleId FROM @Cycle WHERE idx = @i)

        INSERT  INTO @MyTempTable
        EXEC       usp_cust_GetTransactionsByCycle @CycleId
        SET @i = @i + 1

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

If I could either unpivot my row of unknown length and unknown columns then this would work I think.

I also thought there was a way to insert into a table by wrapping values, so it chops a long row of data into x rows matching the length of the new table.

Then again there may be another way to iterate up a table of unknown length and unknown columns names.

SQL might be the wrong way to go, I just fear SSRS is pushing me in this direction, I don't know if I can do the foreach in SSRS instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about how to transform string into table then yuo can use STRING_SPLIT

```
 DECLARE @InString VARCHAR(20);
 SET @InString='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';
 SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@InString,',');
```

Comment: Hi @sergey it's about turning a row into a column.  SSRS seems to be delivering a series of values so (1,2,3,4) where I need (1),(2),(3),(4) not a csv string '1,2,3,4' I guess I may be able to get SSRS to convert to a string.  If I tell it to use text type?

Comment: If I try and split string the SSRS provided param, it fails with has "too many arguments specified"  I don't think it's shipping a string out to SQL.

Comment: So I think I can serialise the data in SSRS before sending to SQL.  Then the string_split() will work.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a kind of madness but I found a workaround to get a table of values from the results from SSRS.  I query the IDs against a source table using IN().

```sql
SELECT [TblFeeBillingCycleID] 
FROM [TblFeeBillingCycle] 
WHERE [TblFeeBillingCycleID] IN(@intCycleId)
```