# What is the SSRS Multi Value Data Type and how to use

Tags: reporting-services

I have a multi-select.

[image]

I think the underlying datatype is int || array(int).  This is pretty frustrating that you have to do a check to see if a multi-value is present before jumping into an index.  But how does this value get passed to SQL?

It's easy enough to use in a IN (@variable) statement.  How else can it be used?  Is it a string or a table. From my investigations it appears to be single table row with many un-named columns but I'm not really sure.

Finally, when you want to simulate a multi-select in a query inside visual studio, for example to "Refresh Fields" how do you do that? For example "1,2,3", {1,2,3} or @{1,2,3}.  It's not (123) because that is -123.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It dpends what you are trying to do and in what context.

As you said, if you have a datset query that is a SQL script (as opposed to a stored proc) then you can use `IN(@paramName)`. In this instance SSRS take the parameter **values** (not the labels) and injects them into the sql statement as a string e.g. `'1,2,3'`. The result would be `IN(1,2,3)`. If you want to pass in a list of, say, countries then you would have to set the parameter values to be the same as the parameter labels So rather then Value =1, Label = Spain you would have Value = Spain and Label = Spain. Used in an `IN()` would generate something like `IN('Spain', 'France')`.

If you try to do the same with a stored proc e.g. `EXEC myProc @myParam`, then the parameter values would be passed as a sing string which would then need to be split out by the proc.

If you just want to get a list of selected parmeter values or label shoing in your report then you can simply do something like

```
=JOIN(Parameters!myParam.Value, ",")
```

or

```
=JOIN(Parameters!myParam.Label, ",")
```

where `","` is the delimiter

If you pop this expression in a text box, you'll get a list of the selected parmater values/labels

Comment: Thanks Alan, this is somewhat helpful.  My question is rather 3 which is perhaps the problem.  Do you know what you might put in the Define Query Params to get a test query going?  I have another Question here which is a little more specific about uses in SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298268/ssrs-multi-select-and-for-each-stored-procs/69298904#69298904

Comment: So I think that I can serialise the data getting sent to SQL by sending JOIN(Parameters!myParam.Value, ",") rather than Parameters!myParam.Value.  Then I can spit the string and potentially cast back to int

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a kind of madness but I found a workaround to get a table of values from the results from SSRS.  I query the IDs against a source table using IN().  I hope there is a better way of doing this?

```sql
SELECT [TblFeeBillingCycleID] 
FROM [TblFeeBillingCycle] 
WHERE [TblFeeBillingCycleID] IN(@intCycleId)
```